Google API distancematrix returns an empty value
I am developing a PHP application to calculate the distance between 2 locations.
This is the code:
$GOOGLE_API_KEY = <MYAPIKEY>
$wayFrom = urlencode($wayFrom);
$wayTo = urldecode($wayTo); 
$url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?units=imperial&origins=".$wayFrom."&destinations=".$wayTo."&key=".$GOOGLE_API_KEY;
$out = @file_get_contents($url);
$data = json_decode($out);
$km = (int)($data->rows[0]->elements[0]->distance->value / 1000);

but from the file_get_contents statement I get an empty string.
The thing that bothers me the most is that, by inserting the string of the $url variable in the address of a browser, the call to the API works and I get the expected json code.
What could it be?

Is there any point in using urlencode on one variable and urldecode on the other?

Do you get any error if you remove the @ ?

@Nico, Sometimes you look for your glasses for hours and find out that they are on your nose :-)
Thanks, that was just it!
